# How do you add the first site to a graph in a web crawler?

Tags: python, web, dictionary

I'm trying to write a web crawler program but am having trouble understanding a pretty simple concept about dictionaries. I want to make a graph (dictionary) of the links on a website. here is my code:

```
def crawl(site, graph, dist):
    links = analyze(site)
    graph.add(site)              ##graph[site].add(site)? but site isn't yet a key..
    for link in links:
        parsedurl = urlparse(link)
        desc = parsedurl.netloc
        if parsedurl.scheme != 'http' or parsedurl.scheme != 'https':
             continue
        else:
            if link in site:
                continue
            else:
                graph[site].add(link)
    return graph
```

I can't figure out how to add the site to the graph, since I need to have a key for the graph (otherwise I get the error message "dict object has no attribute 'add'") but the graph is empty so site isn't yet a key.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just remove `graph.add(site)`.Why do you need it?

Comment: because I need to add the website to the dictionary... and graph[site] won't work down below if I don't somehow make site a key earlier in the code

Comment: well once I get this to work, I'm hoping to have it recursively call itself for each link on the website, so I don't think that will solve my problem

Comment: then make both the key as well data as site `graph={}` `graph[site]=site`

Answer (score 0):

Make both the key as well data as site
`graph[site]=site`